# fish Shell: Chaining commands to be run as a background job

Tags: command-line-interface, fish

I'd like to be something along the following at the fish command prompt:

```
$ sleep 120; and echo 'buggery bollocks' &
```

Or, as of fish 3.0:

```
$ sleep 120 && echo 'buggery bollocks' &
```

Or either of the above without the trailing ampersand, then suspending with Ctrl-Z and putting the whole thing into the background with 'bg' command. None of these work.  The first two just do the sleep in the foreground, and I assume the echo in the background.  If I suspend with Ctrl-Z, then 'buggery bollocks' gets output immediately.

I know I could just write a script with those two commands in it, and run it in the background, but I feel I shouldn't have to.  Any experienced fishmongers around who might have an answer for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Fish does not currently support backgrounding anything more complicated than a simple external command.

So as of fish 3.1.2 (and most likely 3.2.0): Yes, you have to write a script with those two commands in it and run it in the background.

Comment: You run a command string directly as a fish subprocess (e.g. `fish --command "sleep 120 && echo 'buggery bollocks'" &`) to "write a script" without having to actually write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

As @faho said fish doesn't support background processes yet, but there is a "hackish" way to do it.

```sh
fish -c 'my_command_1' & fish -c 'another_cmd' & fish -c '3rd_cmd'
```

I use this to start browser-sync and upload scripts in 1 cmd when I develop.